# Assembly language emu8086 loop input. Am I doing this right?

Tags: assembly, input, output, x86-16, emu8086

So, I did this program that loops 5 times and prints back what the user inputted. Instead, what I got for the output is a random generated ascii character. Here is the program:

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data 

num1 db 'Enter a number: $'
num2 db 'Enter a number: $'
num3 db 'Enter a number: $'
num4 db 'Enter a number: $'
num5 db 'Enter a number: $'

msg1 db 'The number is : $' 

temp db ?

.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax


lea dx, num1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov temp,al

mov ah, 2                    
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21H

lea dx, num2
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov temp,al

mov ah, 2                    
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21H

lea dx, num3
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov temp,al

mov ah, 2                    
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21H

lea dx, num4
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov temp,al

mov ah, 2                    
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21H

lea dx, num5
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov temp,al

mov ah, 2                    
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21H





mov cx, 5

print:

mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah   
int 21H

lea dx, msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h
            
mov ah, 2
mov dl,temp

int 21h


loop print  (check the value in CX)

exit:
mov ah,4ch

int 21h
end
```

So, the loop is pretty self-explanatory. Loop and display 5 inputs. Did I miss something or am I approaching this all wrong and basically need to start over? Please shed some light. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: The first part of your program is not a loop, it's **unrolled** five times. You might omit the paragraph which prints new line if you had defined it in the prompt: 
`num1 db 0dh, 0ah, 'Enter a number: $'`

Answer (score 1):

> what I got for the output is a random generated ascii character

Your program inputs 5 characters from the keyboard, **stores these on top of each other because there's only one storage byte defined** (*temp*), and as a consequence the final loop displays the fifth input five times.

Why do you define five identical prompts for inputting a single digit number? What you need is a single prompt and five unique storage locations. Also, instead of repeating the code, write a loop for the input too:

```
msg0 db 'Enter a number: $'
msg1 db 'The number is : $' 
char db  0,0,0,0,0

  ...

  xor bx, bx          ; Index to address the 5 storage bytes
NextInput:
  mov dx, OFFSET msg0
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h             ; -> AL
  mov [char + bx], al
  inc bx
  mov ah, 02h                    
  mov dl, 13
  int 21h
  mov dl, 10   
  int 21h
  cmp bx, 5
  jb  NextInput
```

The second loop will have to be very similar of course.
Use

```
mov dl, [char + bx]
inc bx
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```

to display the characters.